# Making mod_proxy_http send back response asynchronously (w/o 100 Continue)

Tags: apache-2.2, http, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

A servlet engine (Jetty) is running behind an Apache Httpd server, forwarded using `mod_proxy_http`. This is running a small servlet that accepts `PUT` requests and is authenticated using HTTP Basic authentication (handled within Jetty).

When doing a direct (non-proxied) `PUT` request with `curl`, using the wrong authentication credentials, the server returns a 401 status code as expected:

```
curl -v -T testfile -u user:WRONG_PASSWORD http://localhost:8080/myservlet/
```

This interrupts the requests as soon as the status code is received, so curl doesn't upload the whole body, but stops early (`HTTP error before end of send, stop sending`).

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> PUT /myservlet/testfile HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 3672
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: basic realm="Test Realm"
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Jetty(7.4.5.v20110725)
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
< 
* Closing connection #0
```

In contrast, when behind `mod_proxy_http`, there's a `100 Continue` response sent almost straight away by Apache Httpd, which curl does interpret as `continue`, so it sends the entire request (`We are completely uploaded and fine`) before it eventually gets the `401` response.

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> PUT /myservlet/testfile HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: xxxxxx
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
< Server: Jetty(7.4.5.v20110725)
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: basic realm="Test Realm"
< Content-Length: 0
< Via: 1.1 localhost
< Content-Type: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Is there a way to prevent `mod_proxy_http` from using the `100 Continue` code and to make it wait for the `401` status code from the backend server before sending its first response?

I've tried to follow [the following suggestion from this question](https://serverfault.com/a/302539/47187), but this didn't solve the problem (it wasn't quite the same problem anyway):

```
    ProxyPass /myservlet/ http://localhost:8080/myservlet/
    <Location /myservlet/>
            RequestHeader unset Expect early
    </Location>
```

Comment: Interesting.  I don't think this is a solution.. but maybe try setting `ProxyIOBufferSize 512` and `ProxyReceiveBufferSize 512`.  Since your `POST` is smaller than the default 8k buffers, I'm curious if having these in place will kill the transfer before it completes.

Comment: I have the very same problem and here is the report: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60330